# How should I display an image in iReport from Base64 text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a text field in my table that has a value of base64image like this:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAABQCAYAAACeXX40AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAABxpRE9UAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAoAAAAKAAAACgAAAAoAAABm0Xg9YIAAAFnSURBVHgB7NQ/S4VQGMfxe9N7FTEh8M+kIoI2NDdLNATqIthYBwIHx6C5qaGhXkWTryR6Ib0Ne25g3MXbJnf4HvghBx
```

How can I display an image reading this field in iReport 4.0.1?
I used the guideline in [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/504723/image-base64-text) but didn't work. 
it throws following error:

```
SimpleJasperReportsContext cannot be resolved to a type
```

even if I import the required classes to xml file as:

```
<import value="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"/>
```

and add this to my ImageExpression value:

```
 new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64($F{out_sign_in}.getBytes()))
```

I get the following error:

```
Base64 cannot be resolved
```

---

This [link](https://rgauss.com/2009/12/21/jasperreports-xml-datasource-with-inline-images/) solved my problem

Comment: non of the solutions in that link works for me. I have text field that contains byte[] and wanna display as image in a java.lang.string field

Comment: Take a look at the `asPNG` method. You can apply the same technique. Instead of using an SVG stream, you have a Base64 sequence that must be decoded into a `ByteArrayInputStream`. It's the same problem, just dressed up a bit differently.

Comment: I just noticed that when I compile my jrxml file, it removes the import line that I have added to the raw JRXML

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens

Comment: What do you mean the "cannot be resolved" error?, there is something wrong in your import, specify full classpath in call, if you still get error check your classpath